# How to get current location of MapView in NSLog?

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, currentlocation

I am able to get the longitude and altitude of user's current location but, not the name of location . I used userLocation property as below:

```
NSLog(@"Current location=%@",mapView.userLocation);
```

but, it gives me output as 
`Current location=<MKUserLocation: 0x1f59e8c0>`

I want to get the string value of that location instead of 0x1f59e8c0. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting at the MKMapView documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html

You can follow the chain down to find the longitude is part of a CLLocationCoordinate2D (and is a double)
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CLLocationCoordinate2D

```
NSLog(@"Current longitude = %f",mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSLog(@"Current location %@",mapView.userLocation.title);
```

P.S. There's on more property subtitle

Comment: But, this gave me value as , Current location=Current Location